# Как правильно вести цикл разработки в git?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Мне интересен цикл разработки. Наслышан о том, что есть много методологий, которые разбивают ветки проекта в git, например: local, production, release, dev и т.п.

Как правильно вести ветки git-а и в какой последовательности делать коммиты и их пушить (вплоть до прод.сервера)?

Comment: Вот тут много об этом написано: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Answer (score 1):

На этот вопрос невозможно ответить. Все зависит от множества различных факторов (размер проекта, размер команды и т.д.) Правильной методологии не существует, есть та, которая больше всего подходит вам в текущий момент. Но чаще всего я встречал GitFlow.

Comment: К примеру проект на python, django - rest api к интернет магазину с возможностью написания приложения на android, ios.

Comment: Если на проекте будут работать 3-4 человека, каждый будет заниматься своим отдельным куском (backend, ios, android), вы не пишите тесты и нет команды тестировщиков, то вам о таких вещать можно даже не задумываться.